# TFS merge points

Tags: tfs, merge

is there a good way in Team Explorer (or other) to take a folder and get a list of all the branch points in it? I have some legacy source that was cut up and branched into a nicer folder structure. This legacy source has been supported while the new project was stabilized and now i need to take those bug fixes up to the new structure but its a bit hairy and im hoping i don't miss anything. In retrospect some good documentation would have been the best answer but its too late for that now :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you mean by "branch points in [a folder]"?  I'm imagining this could mean any of:

1. Files & folders underneath the folder that have been used as the source of a Branch operation.  I.e., there is another "copy" of said file/folder somewhere else in the tree that you need to track down & merge back to the original location.
2. Files & folders that have been the target of a Branch or Merge operation coming from another part of the tree.  I.e. the opposite of situation #1.
3. Files & folders that have been modified in-place.  (i.e. "branch point" is just a fancy name for "change I want to enumerate and do something with")

Comment: Number 1 :) I have a folder and in that folder I have an unknown quantity of files and or folders that were the source of a branch operation. I would like to be able to quickly find out what files and folders these are without just trying merge on everything and seeing if i get anything that i can merge to...

Comment: I'd recommend the command line.  'tf merges $/somefolder -recursive -format:detailed' should enumerate which items have been branched & where.